# How long does advantage last in football?

Tags: rules, football, officiating

I've seen the referee award advantage (and the announcer will indicate as much).  I get the sense that advantage only lasts for the next couple of touches.  I've seen possession get turned over and a free kick not awarded afterward.

So, **how long does advantage last after awarded?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in [Law 5 "The Referee", Section 3 "Powers and Duties"](https://www.theifab.com/laws/chapter/25/section/54/):

> [The referee] allows play to continue when an offence occurs and the non-offending team will benefit from the advantage, and penalises the offence if the anticipated advantage does not ensue at that time or within a few seconds

i.e. either the offence has to be penalised within a few seconds, or play is allowed to continue; the referee cannot "go back" more than those few seconds.